# vscode "Run Without Debugging" doesn't open Python Debug Console

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VSCode's "Run Without Debugging" runs the python file (I can tell from time passing) but it doesn't open any panel/terminal to show the output.

I have uninstalled/reinstalled the Microsoft python extension, and run the above experiment outside of any workspace, in a brand new directory with a single "test.py" file, after quitting/reopening VSCode.

How do I get VSCode to open the "Python Debug Console" upon "Run Without Debugging"?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the contents of `pythonpath` in your `setting.json` manually.

```
"python.pythonpPath":"the location of your python.exe" #Note that python.EXE is used here. If you use conda environment, the default configuration may be set to pythonw.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another possible solution.

You can specify the shell in `setting.json` by adding the following code:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",
```

Of course, this method is outdated, and we will also receive warnings (but it will not affect its effectiveness):

[image]

According to the [update of document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_terminal-profiles), we can name the terminal and specify the default terminal in the following way:

```
    {
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "My PowerShell": {
      "path": "pwsh.exe",
      "args": [
         "-noexit",
         "-file",
         "${env:APPDATA}\PowerShell\my-init-script.ps1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "My PowerShell"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

At the top of the menu bar theres a tab named "Terminal" click that and then hit new terminal

Comment: I can also create new terminals from within the panel. Also a terminal window appears if I run the command "Python: Run File in Terminal". But this doesn't solve my question: "Run Without Debugging" still fails to open the panel / show output.