# VSCode run without debugging doesn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Using VSCode I can run my test python code by pressing the play icon top right.

This should = run without debugging but I get no output

I have tried adding python path to settings.json as per

[vscode "Run Without Debugging" doesn't open Python Debug Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73001241/vscode-run-without-debugging-doesnt-open-python-debug-console)

but no change.

Not a big issue but any non workaround solutions.

Comment: Hi, can you use shortcut `ctrl+~` to call out the terminal and use command `python xxx.py` to run the file and get the result in the terminal?

Comment: This didn't pop out the terminal. For some reason create a debug file has fixed this issue for me, although now the debugger doesn't appear to be working e.g. creating a variable not listed under variables. I will research.

Comment: Can you run Python files in an external CMD window?

Comment: Yes if I load the terminal separately. Python is in PATH

Comment: Whether updating or reinstalling vscode is effective. If it cannot be solved, please submit it to [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I Fixed: Re-installing the debugger (in my case  IntelliSense)

1. File Menu "Run" - "Install Additional Debuggers..."
2. Then in the actual debugger (Generally the first) select Uninstall
3. Restart VScode
4. File Menu "Run" - "Install Additional Debuggers..."
5. Search and install the debugger again
6. Try

Answer (score 0):

I also updated a new answer in your [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73001241/vscode-run-without-debugging-doesnt-open-python-debug-console/73244565#73244565).

You can specify the shell in **setting.json** by adding the following code:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",
```

Of course, this method is outdated, and we will also receive warnings (but it will not affect its effectiveness):

[image]

According to the update of [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics#_terminal-profiles), we can name the terminal and specify the default terminal in the following way:

```
    {
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "My PowerShell": {
      "path": "pwsh.exe",
      "args": [
         "-noexit",
         "-file",
         "${env:APPDATA}\PowerShell\my-init-script.ps1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "My PowerShell"
}
```

Comment: No change from either suggestion. :(

Comment: Can you answer the questions in the comments? You can also try the [code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension.

Answer (score 0):

Recently stumbled upon the same problem myself. While running some tests on JavaScript(Node.js as runtime). On a script file with nothing, but a simple console.log('Works!'); it would not print out on the Debug Console using the default Node.js launch configuration. From what I understand it seems to be a Debugger issue of VS Code(ver-1.87). Possible solutions:

1. It should be fixed in the nightly version [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug#nightly-extension)
2. Install an older version version. [Ver-1.83](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_83) is what specifically worked for me.